# Sending commands to iPhone app through  Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I am working on an iPhone application and I was wondering if I can send a command from my server to activate my application, at which point my app would contact the server with my payload.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a notification to your app saying there are changes.

If the user decides to start of the app as a result of the notification, you could then check for the payload.

You can't automatically start the app with APS though.